# ubuntu filesystem display names in df -hT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I have an older linux system that has a certain file structure that we need for a program we use. im building a new ubuntu server to take over for the older one and im trying to make the filesystem name be the same as the old one.  the picture is of the old one and as you see it has /dev/mapper/vg_pgsnew-lv_root listed as the filesystem name. on ubuntu if i go into Gparted and edit the filesystem name it still shows as dev/sdeb1. how do i get ubuntu to actually change the name to /dev/mapper/vg_pgsnew-lv_root ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using LVM on the new server? If so, what name did you use in creating the VG? Along with this, you have a screenshot of the old system but not the new. Seeing both would help.  Even better would be if you included the text of the output in your post instead of having us go to an external link to a picture that cannot be indexed.

Comment: im not allowed to embed images untill i get more points, but i put in the new server lay out too. pertinent line is the last one

Comment: Additional comment - the file structure is independent of the underlying physical hardware. /foo/bar/blah will always appear the same no matter if / is mounted on /dev/sda, /dev/mapper/blah, nfs://whatever. Relying on hardware devices is a really bad idea.

Comment: Don't embed images. Include the necessary text in a code block. And since the new server was not built using LVM, you will not get the same device names. Similarly, if you used NVMe drives or some RAID controllers you'll also not manage the same device names.

Comment: `/dev/mapper/xyz` is a pretty typical path for LVM volumes. Run `vgs`, `pvs`, and `lvs` on both systems to compare the volume groups, physical volumes, and logical volume configs, respectively. You should not need to rename the devices if the mount points are the same, but you could do that in fstab or by messing with your boot loader

Comment: @Cpt.Whale From the `df` output, the OP does not have the system built with LVM. They are restricted to the `/dev/sd*`, `/dev/nvme*`, or `/dev/hd*` type device names. Only option would be to go into udev rules and rename the devices at the system level.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).